# Вывести полученную прибыль от проданных товаров за апрель 2022 года

Tags: sql

Необходимо сделать так, не совсем понимаю, как преобразовать в код.

Основная таблица `sales`, присоединяете к ней таблицу `price as zak` для того, чтобы вывести закупочную цену.

То есть у вас будет два условия присоединения по товару само собой, и по виду цены равное закупочной. То же самое проделываете для оптовой или розничной цены (тут разницы не будет), то есть присоединяете также `price`, только с видом цены, равное оптовой или розничной.

Затем вам необходимо будет сделать вычисляемое поле, то есть `SUM` (цена розничная/оптовая отнять цену ЗАКУПОЧНАЯ) и это все в группировке по месяцу апрель и году 2022, только вам в поля выводить товары не нужно, только год, месяц, и вычисляемое поле, которое считает прибыль и все.

Мой код выдаёт нули.

```
SELECT
SUM((price_op.PRICE - price_zak.PRICE) * sale.KOL) AS PROFIT
FROM
sale
JOIN price AS price_op ON sale.P_ID = price_op.P_ID AND price_op.KP_ID = (SELECT ID FROM kind_price WHERE NAME = 'Оптовая')
JOIN price AS price_zak ON sale.P_ID = price_zak.P_ID AND price_zak.KP_ID = (SELECT ID FROM kind_price WHERE NAME = 'Закупочная')
WHERE sale.date_sale >= '2022-04-01' AND sale.date_sale < '2022-04-30'
GROUP BY sale.date_sale
ORDER BY sale.date_sale DESC;][1]]
```

[Таблицы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEKTv.jpg)